# javascript validation is not working on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

i want to insert data into mysql using javascript and ajax. when i want to validate modal form it's not working. 
here is my javascript code.

```
 // ajax adding data to database
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    {

        if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
        {
            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
            reload_table();
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
            {
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
            }
        }
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error adding data');
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

    }
});
```

My Validation Code is for save data to database and validation of that data

```
public function ajax_add() { 
    $this->_validate();
    $data = array( 
            'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'), 
            'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'), 
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'), 
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'), 
             'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'), 
          );
   $insert = $this->person->save($data); 
  echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
```

}

Comment: Put the validation code also here

Comment: my controller code is here.

    public function ajax_add()
 {
  $this->_validate();
  $data = array(
    'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'),
    'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'),
    'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
    'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
    'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
   );
  $insert = $this->person->save($data);
  echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
 }